# Warning: Task "clean:server" not found

Tags: node.js, terminal, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

If I use any grunt task it throws this error. Someone on the irc channel said it was possible that my gruntfile was corrupt, but there is no information on the internet that could help me learn to fix this issue

```
Warning: Task "(some task)" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-07-22 18:06:52 UTC)
loading tasks   5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 28%
serve          12ms     ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 67%
Total 18ms
```

If I do grunt serve the error says that task "clean:server can be found".
but my gruntfile contains clean server

```
clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    }
```

Here is the entire gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-07-22 using generator-webapp 0.4.9
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths
var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: config,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['bowerInstall']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        sass: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            open: true,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                open: false,
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
        options: {
            loadPath: [
                'bower_components'
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        },
        server: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '.tmp/styles',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    bowerInstall: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
            exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
        },
        sass: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}']
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
        },
        html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
        dist: {
            devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
                ]
            },
            uglify: true
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'sass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer'
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
```

};

Comment: Make sure a `package.json` exists with the tasks specified. As that is what `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` uses to load those tasks. Also make sure they're installed and exist in `./node_modules/` relative to your `Gruntfile.js`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you accidentally deleted some file in the node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean directory.
Delete this dir and repeat the npm install. I also detected the problem and this worked for me.